# How to predict using a locally smoothed mean?

Tags: r

(Statistics beginner here).

I have some training data (x,y), and wish to make prediction for new data x_new.

Now let's assume I have the data for the plot below, but I do not know how y is computed. So I would like to use the data I have a calculate for any given x the local mean of y data, as this seems like the best guess I can make.

```
install.packages("gplots")
library("gplots")

x <- abs(rnorm(500))
y <- rnorm(500, mean=2*x, sd=2+2*x)
bandplot(x,y)
```

[image]

Is there a R function to **predict y for a given x**, using the locally smoothed mean (here shown in red thanks to the function bandplot), or something similar?

Comment: is this the same question as:http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84288/locally-smoothed-mean-r-gplots-bandplot-how-to-get-the-values?rq=1

Comment: No, the present question above is more generic. The other question you linked to was about bandplot only. Please do not close this question.

Comment: (1) Question is fairly common. Nonparameteric functions in stats software rarely have a "predict" option. I sort of understand the philosophy behind that, but can be annoying. (2) This is sort of a software issue (3) Often you just have to create the function yourself to extract the values (4) I've usually gotten around it by using a semi-parametric model instead (something GAM, but I've forgotten if R GAM has predict option)

Comment: If you pose related questions you should make that explicit. I think it's better to extend your previous question and to close this one.

Answer (score 0):

`wapply` from [gplots](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots/gplots.pdf) returns the locally smoothed mean as a table for x and y.

```
x <- 1:1000
y <- rnorm(1000, mean=1, sd=1 + x/1000 )
wapply(x,y,mean)
```

to predict, one would need, I guess, to resolve the closest x that is in the table returned by wapply, then deduce the local mean for y.

For a value a, the closest x will be given by the index:

```
index = which(abs(wapply(x,y,mean)$x-a)==min(abs(wapply(x,y,mean)$x-a)))
```

then the prediction should be:

```
pred = wapply(x,y,mean)[index]
```

So in one line:

```
locally_smoothed_mean_prediction = function(a) wapply(x,y,mean)$y[which(abs(wapply(x,y,mean)$x-a)==min(abs(wapply(x,y,mean)$x-a)))]
> locally_smoothed_mean_prediction(600)
[1] 1.055642
```